# mariabackup: empty backup file

Tags: mariadb, centos7, database-backups

I'm trying to automate our backups of some mysql databases in MariaDB Server 10.2.15 on CentOS 7.5:

```
mariabackup --backup --target-dir=/srv/db_backup --databases="wordpress" --xbstream | \ 
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -k mysecretpassword > \ 
$(date +"%Y%m%d%H").backup.xb.enc
```

What I expect is a file in `/srv/db_backup` called `$(date +"%Y%m%d%H").backup.xb.enc`

What I'm finding is a file called `$(date +"%Y%m%d%H").backup.xb.enc` in my home directory with file size 0, and the `/srv/db_backup` dir looks like:

```
[root@wordpressdb1 ~]# ls -la /srv/db_backup/
total 77868
-rw-------  1 root root    16384 Jul 31 14:30 aria_log.00000001
-rw-------  1 root root       52 Jul 31 14:30 aria_log_control
-rw-------  1 root root      298 Jul 31 14:30 backup-my.cnf
-rw-------  1 root root      938 Jul 31 14:30 ib_buffer_pool
-rw-------  1 root root 79691776 Jul 31 14:30 ibdata1
-rw-------  1 root root     2560 Jul 31 14:30 ib_logfile0
drwx------  2 root root       19 Jul 31 14:30 wordpress
-rw-------  1 root root      103 Jul 31 14:30 xtrabackup_checkpoints
-rw-------  1 root root      458 Jul 31 14:30 xtrabackup_info
```

All further attempts to run the mariabackup command fail on:

```
mariabackup: Can't create/write to file '/srv/db_backup/ib_logfile0' \
(Errcode: 17 "File exists")
mariabackup: error: failed to open the target stream for 'ib_logfile0'.
```

What have I done wrong?

**EDIT**
First error was a missing dash in openssl -aes-256-cbc

Now I'm seeing this:

```
180731 15:18:37 Executing FLUSH NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG TABLES...
Error: failed to execute query FLUSH NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG TABLES: Access \
denied; you need (at least one of) the RELOAD privilege(s) for this operation
```

I've granted both SUPER and RELOAD to root user, still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

"What I expect is a file in `/srv/db_backup` called `$(date +"%Y%m%d%H").backup.xb.enc`" -- Then you need to specify a directory other than the current directory:

```
mariadbdump ... > \
/srv/db_backup/$(date +"%Y%m%d%H").backup.xb.enc
```

As for "unable to write", what do you get from

```
ls -ld /srv/db_backup
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **--stream=xbstream** , not **--xbstream**

You backed up into directory, not into stream.